# Find the object in the $scope that have a key starting with a certain string?

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have a list of text field like this

```
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" name="option1" ng-model="option1" /></li>
        <li><input type="text" name="option2" ng-model="option2" /></li>
    </ul>
```

I'd like to find all of the option* that are in the  $scope
Thank you in advance for the answer

Comment: I'd like to obtain an array of the value of the options of the list

Comment: Please elaborate it

Comment: So, why not bind to an array instead? Such as `ng-model="option[0]"`?

Comment: The problems is that I don't know the number of the text fields in the list. The application has by default two list but there is also a button that permit the user to add new options programmatically. So with Jquery i add in every text field a progressive number in the ng-model. The first ng-model=option1, the second option2, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an array which will hold the input data and then add a loop to iterate over this array in html. You will then not need to search in scope for specific objects, you will have the array ready.

```
$scope.allOptions = [
    {name: 'option1', text: ''},
    {name: 'option2', text: ''}
];
```

And then:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="option in allOptions"><input type="text" name="{{option.name}}" ng-model="option.text" /></li>
</ul>
```

> The problems is that I don't know the number of the text fields in the list. The application has by default two list but there is also a button that permit the user to add new options programmatically. So with Jquery i add in every text field a progressive number in the ng-model. The first ng-model=option1, the second option2, ...

I recommend to use angular then (to add another input).

```
$scope.addInput = function(){
    var n = $scope.allOptions.length;
    $scope.allOptions.push({name: 'option'+(n+1), text: ''});
};

<button ng-click="addInput()">Awesomeness is here</button>
```

Comment: Clear problem -> clear solution, I don't understand your point... No words need to be added

Comment: i agree with @cale_b need explanation also. not only code

Comment: Sure.  Clear problem.  Clear solution **to you**.  OP, and future visitors, may have no knowledge of `ng-repeat`, how it works, where to find documentation on it, etc.

Comment: OK, some words added sir

Comment: The problems is that I don't know the number of the text fields in the list. The application has by default two list but there is also a button that permit the user to add new options programmatically. So with Jquery i add in every text field a progressive number in the ng-model. The first ng-model=option1, the second option2, ...

Comment: Edited, check this out

Answer (score -1):

There's a few ways to do this.

[See this working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/d9f7Lsh9/)

The first method I'm showing you would be the natural next step to the way you've done it, and would allow you to access the values as you request.

First, bind your inputs to an array, like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="option[1]" ng-model="option[0]" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="option[2]" ng-model="option[1]" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="option[3]" ng-model="option[2]" /></li>
</ul>
```

Don't forget to declare your variable as an array in the controller:

```
$scope.option = [];
```

Then, in your controller, you can access them via `$scope.option`.

A more advanced, and simpler / easier to maintain method might be to use`ng-repeat`, which is very powerful.  [ng-repeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

To use `ng-repeat`:

First, set up the array of objects in your controller, like so:

```
$scope.rOptions = [
   {name: 'option1', val: ''},
   {name: 'option2', val: ''},
   {name: 'monkey', val: ''}
];
```

Then, you can output the HTML with a simplified set of markup:

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="rOption in rOptions"><input name="{{rOption.name}}" ng-model="rOption.val"></li>
</ul>
```

And, in your controller, you can access the values via `$scope.rOption`.

You can check out the fiddle above to see how these two work, and how the data can be accessed.